# Powershell WMI Win32_process remote command issues

Tags: powershell, win32-process

I have this command below that uses the WMI and Win32_process to run a command on a remote computer.The computer is called 7-df-1 in the example below.

I am having an issue with my quotes I have tried single and double quotes but the command still doesn't work. It's supposed to download a Surface firmware installer to the C drive on the remote computer.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for looking into this

```
([WMICLASS]"\\7-df-1\Root\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create(“ (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadfile('https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/C/6ACB37C4-E4C1-4E0E-BBAE-AC7A0C303593/SurfacePro4_Win10_15063_1701801_0.msi', 'c:\save.msi')”)
```

Comment: This looks like something that would create a process; but you are trying to run a Powershell script, so it's hard to see how this would work. You probably should look into the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create() method accepts commandline as string, so if you simply give a PowerShell cmdlets/expression it won't recognize.

So you have to mention the handler for the particular commanline you give.

```
([WMICLASS]"\\localhost\Root\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create(“Powershell.exe -c &{ (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadfile('https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/C/6ACB37C4-E4C1-4E0E-BBAE-AC7A0C303593/SurfacePro4_Win10_15063_1701801_0.msi', 'c:\save.msi')}”)
```

You can get help infor for Create() method for Win32_Process [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

**Bad answer.  See comments section.**

I agree with @NullUserException, Invoke-Command is the cmdlet to be using for this.  I advise you try it.

With that said, I can't test your command in my environment but it looks like you're trying to pass a literal command to the remote machine as a string.  In that case you want to use [HereStrings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  They are the step above single quotes.  Try this:

```
([WMICLASS]"\\7-df-1\Root\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create(@' (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadfile('https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/C/6ACB37C4-E4C1-4E0E-BBAE-AC7A0C303593/SurfacePro4_Win10_15063_1701801_0.msi', 'c:\save.msi') '@)
```

Comment: Here string can't be in a single line, it can't have anything in the first line after it starts and the last line can't be intended and should be alone without any thing before the end tag.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Good to know.